# Problems while deserialization of QSettings

Tags: qt

The attempt to persist a QList using the QSettings.setValue() method seems to work well, but after restarting the application, the attempt to deserialize gives the error message:

```
QVariant::load: unknown user type with name QList<QString>
```

persisting code:

```
QSettings settings;     
QList<QString> data {"first", "second", "third"};
settings.setValue("sourceList", QVariant::fromValue(data));
```

primitive types of objects are working well. What is going wrong?

Comment: change `QList<QString>` to `QStringList`

Comment: I didn't mention, that the problem occurs on my linux x86_64 environment, but there seems not be a problem on WIN32 or APPLE. The above workaround is working well on linux, but the example is working code on WIN32 and APPLE, and with the workaround the application will get incompatible with existing installations and persistent data on the disk.

Comment: In Windows and Mac OS do you have the error message: `QVariant::load: unknown user type with name QList<QString>` ?

Comment: I have no Windows or Mac OS, but the application is running since about 1 year, without any reported problem on these platforms

Comment: use a #define to implement the logic:  `#if defined(Q_OS_LINUX) QStringList data {"first", "second", "third"}; #else QList<QString> data {"first", "second", "third"}; #endif` although I think that my solution is compatible with all OS.

Comment: thanks for this idea, but the primary issue, why QT behaves different on LINUX and the other platforms is still open

Comment: It's probably a bug, report it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

After analyzing the existing code, I identified, that a registration of an stream operator, before the QApplication is instantiated, solves the problem.

```
qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<QList<QString>>("Data");
QApplication a(argc, argv);
```

Why this seems not to be necessary on non linux environment is not clear to me.